# Consuming the audio stream with OkHttp

Tags: java, http, okhttp, audio-streaming

I want to consume the following audio stream with Java - https://playoutonestreaming.com/proxy/bylr?mp=/stream.

Main goal is pretty simple - I want to create a service, which would allow me to have 300-400 active connections (e. g. active listeners) at the moment. The problem appears when I try to make a connection with OkHttp.

Here is the code I have:

1. Task for consuming the stream

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class ListenStream implements Runnable {
    private static final String STREAM_URL = "https://playoutonestreaming.com/proxy/bylr?mp=/stream";
    private final OkHttpClient client;
    private final int id;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Clip clip;
        try {
            log.info("[TASK-{}] - Connecting to the stream...", id);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(STREAM_URL)
                    .get()
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            assert response.body() != null;
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.body().bytes());
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("Finished listening to the stream");
        } catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            log.error("Failed to process audio stream");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

2. Executor

```
public class RadioMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .callTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .followSslRedirects(true)
                .build();

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(300);
        List<Runnable> tasks = IntStream.range(1, 301)
                .mapToObj(number -> new ListenStream(client, number))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        tasks.forEach(service::submit);
        service.awaitTermination(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```

With the following approach, I have to set the timeout for OkHttpClient, and then make a request using it. But, as soon as the timeout appears, I'm getting an `InterruptedIOException: socket closed`, and I need to create a new task.
Is there a correct way to consume an audio stream with OkHttp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call timeout will fail the request after that length of time, so remove that setting or define it as 0.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/call-timeout/

> Sets the default timeout for complete calls. A value of 0 means no
> timeout, otherwise values must be between 1 and Integer.MAX_VALUE when
> converted to milliseconds.
>
> The call timeout spans the entire call: resolving DNS, connecting,
> writing the request body, server processing, and reading the response
> body. If the call requires redirects or retries all must complete
> within one timeout period.
>
> The default value is 0 which imposes no timeout.